# When I hover over an element why won't the whole content box change color? There's empty space to the left

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to create a responsive side menu to slide in and out.  I want the hover states of each element to extend the full width of the container but for some reason there is always a gap and I can't get the text to align to the right.  I have tried everything I know and researched as best as I could and found nothing.  Could someone help me understand what is going wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Brushworks NW Inc.</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar animated fadeIn">
        <span class="open-slide">
            <a href="#" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
                <svg width="30" height="30">
                    <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/>
                    <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/>
                    <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/>
                </svg>
            </a>
        </span>
        <ul class="navbar-links">
            <li><a class="active" href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
            <li id="number">(360) 679-4444</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="side-hidden">

    </div>
    <div id="side-menu" class="side-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn-close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">&times;</a></li><br>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script>
        function openSlideMenu(){
          document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '250px';
        }

        function closeSlideMenu(){
          document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '0';
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

```css
body, html{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.container{
    max-width: 980px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

/*-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
<!--                                  NAVIGATION                                         -->
<!-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --*/

.navbar {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #CE2026;
}
.navbar-links {
    max-width: 1090px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 30px;
}

.navbar-links a:hover {
    background: #831517;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: background 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition-property: background;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-delay: 0s;
 }

.navbar-links a {
    display: inline;
    color: #444444;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px 17px;
    right: 25px;
}

nav .active {
    background: #CE2026;
    color: #FFFFFF;
 }

.navbar ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}


ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}


#number {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 85px;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.side-hidden {
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.6;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}

/* Responsive Menu*/
.open-slide {
    float: right;
    z-index: 5;
    display: none;
}

.side-nav {
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #111;
    opacity: 0.9;
    transition: 0.5s;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    z-index: 6;
}

.side-nav ul {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ccc;
    z-index: 6;
}

.side-nav ul a {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 130px 10px 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ccc;
    margin-right: 20px;
    z-index: 6;
    right: 30px;
    text-align: right;
}

.side-nav .btn-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 22px;
    font-size: 36px;

}

.side-nav a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #CE2026;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .navbar-links {
    display: none;
  }

  .open-slide {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 3.5%;
  }
}
```

First minimize the screen to toggle the mobile view.  When you click the hamburger menu it slides out.  But when you hover over the nav links only a portion of the element block highlights red instead of the full width.  And the highlight blocks are supposed to be one right on top of the other, but there's gaps between the nav links.  I don't know why I can't get it to do what I want and I feel like I've tried everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your unordered list inside #side-menu a padding of 0px; then remove `right: 30px;` from the anchors inside `.nav-item`. I also tweaked with some of your properties to make it work. You can see the working code bellow(See in full page view):

```css
body, html{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.container{
    max-width: 980px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

/*-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
<!--                                  NAVIGATION                                         -->
<!-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --*/

.navbar {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #CE2026;
}
.navbar-links {
    max-width: 1090px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 30px;
}

.navbar-links a:hover {
    background: #831517;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: background 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition-property: background;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-delay: 0s;
 }

.navbar-links a {
    display: inline;
    color: #444444;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px 17px;
    right: 25px;
}

nav .active {
    background: #CE2026;
    color: #FFFFFF;
 }

.navbar ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}


ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}


#number {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 85px;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.side-hidden {
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.6;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}

/* Responsive Menu*/
.open-slide {
    float: right;
    z-index: 5;
    display: none;
}

.side-nav {
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #111;
    opacity: 0.9;
    transition: 0.5s;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    z-index: 6;
}

.side-nav ul {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ccc;
    z-index: 6;
    /* Added this */
    padding: 0;
}

/* Added this */
.nav-item {
    display:block;
}

.side-nav ul a {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    /* Changed this */
    /* padding: 10px 130px 10px 100px;*/
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ccc;
    margin-right: 20px;
    z-index: 6;
    /* Removed this */
    /* right: 30px; */
    text-align: right;
    /* Added these */
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.side-nav .btn-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    /* Changed this */
    /* left: 22px; */
    left: 0;
    font-size: 36px;

}

.side-nav a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #CE2026;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .navbar-links {
    display: none;
  }

  .open-slide {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 3.5%;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar animated fadeIn">
        <span class="open-slide">
            <a href="#" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
                <svg width="30" height="30">
                    <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/>
                    <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/>
                    <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/>
                </svg>
            </a>
        </span>
        <ul class="navbar-links">
            <li><a class="active" href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
            <li id="number">(360) 679-4444</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="side-hidden">

    </div>
    <div id="side-menu" class="side-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn-close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">&times;</a></li><br>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script>
        function openSlideMenu(){
          document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '250px';
        }

        function closeSlideMenu(){
          document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '0';
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: thats exactly what I was looking for, but you see how the close button has a taller highlight box than the other links?  How can I make the links hoverboxes stack on top of each other?  Right now theres a gap between them.  The boxes are too short

Comment: nevermind, figured it out!  Thank you! This helped a ton.  In the future, what was I doing wrong that resulted in the problem I had?  Still trying to wrap my head around why

Comment: The close button has a font-size of 36px, which makes it taller. if you want to achieve the same size while having the same height as others, you can give it a line-height of 22.4px. You can mark this as answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help:

1 suggestion instead of changing the width of navbar on click you can use display property (I have implemented this) :

```
<div id="side-menu" style="width:250px; display:none;" class="side-nav">
  .....

<script>
    function openSlideMenu(){
      document.getElementById('side-menu').style.display = 'block';
    }

    function closeSlideMenu(){
      document.getElementById('side-menu').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

```css
body, html{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.container{
    max-width: 980px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

/*-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
<!--                                  NAVIGATION                                         -->
<!-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --*/

.navbar {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #CE2026;
}
.navbar-links {
    max-width: 1090px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 30px;
}

.navbar-links a:hover {
    background: #831517;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: background 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition-property: background;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-delay: 0s;
 }

.navbar-links a {
    display: inline;
    color: #444444;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px 17px;
    right: 25px;
}

nav .active {
    background: #CE2026;
    color: #FFFFFF;
 }

.navbar ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}


ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}


#number {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 85px;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.side-hidden {
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.6;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}

/* Responsive Menu*/
.open-slide {
    float: right;
    z-index: 5;
    display: none;
}

.side-nav {
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #111;
    opacity: 0.9;
    transition: 0.5s;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    z-index: 6;
}

.side-nav ul {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ccc;
    z-index: 6;
}

.side-nav ul a {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 130px 10px 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ccc;
    margin-right: 0%;
    z-index: 6;
    right: 40px;
    text-align: right;
}
 /* Modified this */
.btn-close {
    position: absolute !important;
    font-size: 36px;
    padding: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 0 px;
    text-align: middle !important;
    z-index: 6;
    top: 0px;

}

.side-nav a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #CE2026;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .navbar-links {
    display: none;
  }

  .open-slide {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 3.5%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Brushworks NW Inc.</title>
</head>
<body>








<body>
    <nav class="navbar animated fadeIn">
        <span class="open-slide">
            <a href="#" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
                <svg width="30" height="30">
                    <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/>
                    <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/>
                    <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/>
                </svg>
            </a>
        </span>
        <ul class="navbar-links">
            <li><a class="active" href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
            <li id="number">(360) 679-4444</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="side-hidden">

    </div>
    <div id="side-menu" style="width:250px; display:none;" class="side-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn-close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">&nbsp; &times; &nbsp;</a></li><br>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script>
        function openSlideMenu(){
          document.getElementById('side-menu').style.display = 'block';
        }

        function closeSlideMenu(){
          document.getElementById('side-menu').style.display = 'none';
        }
    </script>

</body>





</body>
</html>
```